# How can we compute $\int \frac{te^t}{(1+t)^2}dt$?

Tags: calculus

This integral seems to be simple to calculate, but i cant. How can we compute $\int \frac{te^t}{(1+t)^2}dt$?

Answer (score 5):

Use integration by parts, to get:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(t\right)=\int\frac{te^t}{\left(1+t\right)^2}\space\text{d}t=-\frac{te^t}{1+t}+\int e^t\space\text{d}t$$

> Integration by parts:
>
> $$\int\text{f}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{g}'\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=\text{f}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{g}\left(t\right)-\int\text{f}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{g}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t$$

Comment: Wondrously simple!  +1

Comment: @SimpleArt Yupp, it surely is :)

Comment: $ f'(t)g(t)=-\frac{te^t}{1+t}$ not $ e^t$?

Comment: your response is wrong.

Comment: @RezaFallah-Moghaddam $f(t)=te^t$ and $g(t)=1/(1+t)$, so $f'(t)g(t)=e^t$.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jan's simple answer, maybe you can do this as well:

---

Let $u=(t+1) $ then our integral becomes $$I=\frac {1}{e } \int \frac {(u-1)e^u }{u^2} =\frac {1}{e}[\int \frac{e^u}{u} du -\int \frac {e^u}{u^2} du] $$ Integrating $\frac {e^u}{u^2} $ By parts where $f=e^u $ and  $g'=\frac {1}{u^2} $, we get, $$\int \frac {e^u}{u^2} =\int \frac {e^u}{u} - \frac {e^u}{u} $$ Rearranging, we get the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: THanks your proof is  correct

Comment: THanks your proof is  correct

Comment: @Reza Fallah-Moghaddam Just substitute.  $\int \frac {e ^u}{u} $ will cancel out giving us $\frac {e^u}{u} $ as the final answer.